# Postgres in Windows - Restoring database - fatal: -1 can only be used in non-interactive mode

Tags: postgresql, non-interactive

I am new to Postgres and I am attempting to load/restore a Postgres database from a database dump file within Windows. When I attempt to do so I get the following error. Being new to Postgres I am not sure what the error means.

**The command**

```
C:\Users\myuser>psql --single-transaction newdatabasename --file="C:\path\to\database-dump-file.sql"
```

**the error**

```
psql: fatal: -1 can only be used in non-interactive mode
```

I entered the command in the windows command shell where the path the Postgres `BIN` directory is included in the `PATH`. What is this error referring to? Do I need to be in the SQL Shell (psql) to execute this command? A Google search seems to indicate it may have something to do with authenticating with a password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, the option parsing library stops parsing arguments once the first non-option argument is encountered.  That means the file argument is not seen, so it thinks you are in interactive mode.

You need to put `newdatabasename` at the end of the command line, not in the middle.